# ReactJS: Determining the index of an item in an array, that is passed from another file. (Using Ant Design)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I have a file with some Javascript code that consists of an array, with multiple object within (with key:value pairs).
Initially, in my main file (App.jsx) I create a State Variable and set it to the array in my other JS file. I am now trying to add a button, which when I click I can determine which Object (item) within the array the value belongs to.

```
               <List
                    bordered
                    className="list-default"
                    dataSource={requestInfo}
                    renderItem={(item) => (
                      <Space>
                        <List.Item>
                          <h4>{"Request Id: " + item.requestId}</h4>
                          <div>
                            {"Request DateTime: " + item.requestDateTime}
                          </div>
                        </List.Item>
                        <Button type="text" onClick={showDetails}>
                          >>
                        </Button>
```

Here's a snippet of my code. Basically, the 'item' in the inline function is one of the objects from the array (requestInfo -> which is a statevariable). I want it to be such that, the button can store the index of the object (item) as its ID. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your Button declaration, you are passing a function reference to onClick prop:

```
<Button type="text" onClick={showDetails}>
```

which is a shortcut to:

```
<Button type="text" onClick={(clickEvent) => showDetails(clickEvent)}>
```

So you can expand this, and call the function with parameters that you need:

```
<Button type="text" onClick={() => showDetails(item.requestId)}>
```